# ubuntu 14.4 not showing WIFI?

Tags: 14.04, networking, wireless

I installed ubuntu 14.4 (x86) on my dell laptop  and after installation no  wifi  showing my on my connection ?

while i run

```
sudo modprobe -r iwlwfi
```

> result :Modprobe:fatal:module iwlwfi not found

```
lspci -vq | grep -i wireless
```

> Result:  Subsystem: Dell Wireless 1390 WLAN miniCard

```
lspci -vq | grep -i wireless
```

> ob:00:0 Network Controller : Broadcom coperation BCM4311 802.11b/g
>   WLAN (rev 01)

How to solve this Error, ubunutu can detect my hardware but it seems not working ?

regards